# Outputting the wrong sum from array of reference

Tags: java

Hi everyone I'm am reading from a csv file a that take a string, years and double. Basically reading a country name, years, and stats of cellular data. Example:

```
Country Name    1960    1961    1962    1963    1964    1965    1966    1967    1968    1969    1970    1971    1972    1973    1974    1975    1976    1977    1978    1979    1980    1981    1982    1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004  
 Aruba           0         0      0       0        0      0       0      0       0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.029310471 0   0   2.138784453 3.605985937 3.98141538  6.16435217  13.48254011 16.50927821 57.05427692 65.05605558 72.10431377 99.64250268.
```

My program is able to read the data but is outputting the wrong sum onto the screen. I created 2 classes. One called subscriptionYear that has two variables called year(stores the year for a subscription data) and subscriptions(stores the number of subscriptions for a specific year). The 2nd class called country stores the country and subscription data from each country. My method getNumSubscriptions is calculating wrongly as it only reads what in 2012 and not doing the total sum. if i input other years it reads the sum as 0 and only read the last year 2012. How can i calculate the sum using the index position of the year to calculate the sum between 1960 to 2012. Please could someone tell me what i did wrong.

```
public class SubscriptionYear {

private int year;
private double subscriptions;

public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    setYear(year);
    setSubscription(subscriptions);
}
public void setYear(int Year)
{
    this.year= Year;
}
public void setSubscription(double value)
{
    this.subscriptions = value;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public double getSubscription()
{
    return subscriptions;
}
public String toString()//returns number of subscriptions
{
    return "Number of Subscriptions: "+subscriptions;
}
}
```

class Country:

```
public class Country {

private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear[] subscriptions;
private int size;

public Country(String country, int arraylength)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.size = arraylength;
    subscriptions = new SubscriptionYear[size];
}
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    for(int i=0;i<subscriptions.length;i++)
    {
        subscriptions[i] = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    }
        System.out.print(subscriptions[0].getYear()+"\t");

}
public double getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(int start, int end)
{
    double sum =0;
    int head = subscriptions[0].getYear()-start;
    int tail = end-start;
    for(int k=head;k<=tail;k++)
    {
        sum += subscriptions[k].getSubscription();
    }
    return sum; 
}
  }
```

TEST FILE:

```
Country [] countries;
    //countries = new Country[NUM_COUNTRIES_TO_TEST];   // Note: Use this for initial testing of your implementation.
    countries = new Country[countryNames.length]; //READS 253 COUNTRIES              

    Country current;

    for (int countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < countries.length; countryIndex++)
    {
        int numberOfYears = yearLabels.length;   // READS THE YEAR BTWN 1960 AND 2012

        current = new Country(countryNames[countryIndex], numberOfYears); //CALLS CONSTRUCTOR

        for (int yearIndex = 0; yearIndex < numberOfYears; yearIndex++)
        {
            double [] allSubscriptions = parsedTable[countryIndex];
            double countryData = allSubscriptions[yearIndex];
            current.addSubscriptionYear(yearLabels[yearIndex], countryData); //STORES THE YEAR AND SUBSCRIPTION DATA OF EACH YEAR
        }
        countries[countryIndex] = current;
    }


    System.out.printf(countryNames[0] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", countries[0].getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(1960,2012));
    // the output is: Aruba (1960 to 2012): 1170.50
```

Should be outputting 1170.50 as total sum but it only outputs 131.86 which is the subscription data for 2012 for aruba.

Comment: time to do some debugging I thinks

Comment: You can remove both set method calls in this constructor `public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)`. They are unnecessary.

Comment: And your `public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)` method looks really strange. It looks like you're overwriting existing `subscriptions` entries with new ones. Now, I'm not surprised that you're getting wrong results.

Comment: @Tom i did remove the setters as it was unnecessary. How will i go about the addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve there. If you want to set a specific entry, then use the same algorithm you used in `getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod`: `subscriptions[subscriptions[0].getYear()-year] = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);`. And don't forget to do some checks. For example if `subscriptions[0].getYear()-year` is smaller than 0 or larger than the array length. Or you're in risk of getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Tom the country class reads the year, and subscriptions data for that year. Each country should have its own data for a specific year. When i placed a system.out.print(subscriptions[0].getYear()) outside the for loop, it read from 1960 to 2012 but did 253 times. As you mentioned i think it overwrites how will you go about each country having its own row of data

Comment: `subscriptions` is an instance variable of each country, therefore every country has it's own data. No need to change something here. And for the rest of that comment: I don't know what you're trying to say there.

Comment: @Tom yes subscriptions is an instance variable of country and each country has its own data. Please bare with me I'm new to programming. subscriptions array stores the year and subscriptions data for each country. When i use the new operator to store each year and data it seems to overwrite the data. How could i avoid this since each country should have its own data not be overwritten. Again please bare with me as i am new to programing.

Comment: Have you tried `subscriptions[subscriptions[0].getYear()-year] = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);` already? (don't forget to remove the `for` loop).

Comment: @Tom yea i tried it and it didn't work. I am required to use the addSubscriptionYear() function as it based on my TestFile class. The addSubscriptionYear() which  takes in the year of type int and a single subscription of type double. Use this to create a new SubscriptionYear object and save it in “subscriptions” array.

Comment: And? No one said to replace the `addSubscriptionYear` method. You should replace the `for` loop in that method with the suggested line.

Comment: @Tom no it didn't work when i replace it

Comment: And what is the result of your debugger?

Answer (score 1):

As Tom pointed out in the comments - the problem lies in `addSubscriptionYear` that for some reason replaces every single entry in subscriptions array to the newest added. Again, citing Tom, the solution could be to use the same algorythm as you used in your `getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod` method:

```
 subscriptions[subscriptions[0].getYear()-year] = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
```

and of course dropping the loop entirely.

You could also drop the weird indexing and always go thorugh the whole array. You have that year parameter in SubscriptionYear for a reason. In add just add SubscriptionYear in the next empty space, and in get go through the whole array and add sum if SubscriptionYear got at the moment is within the bounds.

However using a Map with year as a key and subscription as value for each country would be simpler to wrap your head around than an array with a mysterious algorythm that gets the correct index. Than you would simply have:

```
Map<Integer,Double> subscriptions = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
  subscriptions.put(year,subscription);
}
public double getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(int start, int end)
{
  double sum = 0;
  for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
    sum += subscriptions.get(year);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: i am not allowed to use maps. Instance variable called "subscriptions”, a one dimensional array of type SubscriptionYear, which holds all the subscription data for that country. A constructor that takes in the country name and number of years. We will use this to initialize the size of our “subscriptions” array. addSubscriptionYear” method which  takes in the year of type int and a single subscription of type double. Use this to create a new SubscriptionYear object and save it in “subscriptions” array.

Comment: It's an artificial restriction than made by your teacher, Map is the correct answer if it were a standard problem. However since it's clearly a programming exercise I'm not going to spell the answer. I (through Tom) pointed out what's wrong and what's the possible fix, now it's your job. At least to try and edit your question with next problem you encounter

Comment: from using the system.out.println(subscriptions[0].getYear()); it prints out the year from 1960 to 2012 repeatedly and overwrites the data. I just need a guideline and I'm new to programming. My error seems to come from storing the data.

Comment: It does because it is called every time you call add, printing the year you add. No suprise there. And it overrides the data, that's true, because that's exactly what your code tells him to do. I recommend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging your addSubscriptionYear

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the method:

```
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    for(int i=0;i<subscriptions.length;i++)
    {
        subscriptions[i] = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    }
    System.out.print(subscriptions[0].getYear()+"\t");

}
```

this method create each time an array of subscription with the same value.

you should (at leas) use a list instead of an array and use the .add() method, or use hashmaps with the year as index.

D.

Comment: i am not allowed to use maps. Instance variable called "subscriptions”, a one dimensional array of type SubscriptionYear, which holds all the subscription data for that country. A constructor that takes in the country name and number of years. We will use this to initialize the size of our “subscriptions” array. addSubscriptionYear” method which  takes in the year of type int and a single subscription of type double. Use this to create a new SubscriptionYear object and save it in “subscriptions” array.